# Шифрование текста AES256 java

Tags: java, текст, aes

Всем привет кто может подсказать код AES256

Пример кода должен выглядеть так

```
    public static String test(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(data.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(md.digest());
    }
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte byt : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();                                              
    }                                                                          
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к вашему вопросу?

Comment: https://razilov-code.ru/2018/03/16/aes-java/

Comment: @nick спасибо!!